# Generate (n, 1, 2) arrays with np.tile

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create n times (1,2) arrays and each array should have the same elements. First I generate n times 1 D array and then I use a loop to iterate over these elements and repeat each element to fill (n, 1,2) array. my code is the following:

```
import numpy as np


def u_vec():
   return np.array([np.random.rand(1)])

n=10
u1 = np.zeros(n)

for i in range(n):
    u1[i] = u_vec()

print(u1)

def u_vec1():
    u_vec = np.zeros((n, 2,1))
    for i in range(len(u1)):
        u_vec[i] += np.tile(u1[i], (2,1))
    return u_vec

u = u_vec1()
print(u)
```

the output that I get is

```
[0.4594466  0.80924903 0.3186138  0.03601917 0.9116031  0.68199505
 0.78999837 0.33778259 0.97626521 0.84925156]


[[[0.4594466 0.4594466]]

[[0.        0.       ]]

[[0.        0.       ]]

[[0.        0.       ]]

[[0.        0.       ]]

[[0.        0.       ]]

[[0.        0.       ]]

[[0.        0.       ]]

[[0.        0.       ]]

[[0.        0.       ]]]
```

I do not understand why only the first element is filled but the others are filled with zero. Could someone please help me? Thank you very much!
the output that I would like to have

```
[[[0.4594466 0.4594466]]

[[0.3186138  0.3186138]]

[[ 0.03601917 0.03601917]]

[[ 0.9116031  0.9116031 ]]

[[0.68199505  0.68199505]]

[[0.78999837  0.78999837]]

[[0.33778259  0.33778259]]

[[0.97626521   0.97626521]]

[[0.84925156   0.84925156]]]]
```

Comment: I think is better if you include the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem. The problem is that your `return u_vec` statement is enclosed in the `for` loop. So only the first subarray is updated with the random values and the rest of `u_vec`remains 0 because you return *immediately after the first iteration* of the for loop. You should use

```
def u_vec1():
    u_vec = np.zeros((n, 2,1))
    for i in range(len(u1)):
        u_vec[i] += np.tile(u1[i], (2,1))
    return u_vec # <---- moved outside the for loop
```

Having solved this problem, you might also be interested in knowing an alternative solution using `repeat` and `reshape` to get the desired result as

```
import numpy as np

n=10
u1 = np.random.rand(n)
print(u1)

u = np.repeat(u1,2).reshape((n,2,1))
print(u)
```

---

```
[0.17106854 0.7346424  0.53370937 0.39838919 0.42247593 0.61545304
 0.97014742 0.85912941 0.51137618 0.08148184]
[[[0.17106854]
  [0.17106854]]

 [[0.7346424 ]
  [0.7346424 ]]

 [[0.53370937]
  [0.53370937]]

 [[0.39838919]
  [0.39838919]]

 [[0.42247593]
  [0.42247593]]

 [[0.61545304]
  [0.61545304]]

 [[0.97014742]
  [0.97014742]]

 [[0.85912941]
  [0.85912941]]

 [[0.51137618]
  [0.51137618]]

 [[0.08148184]
  [0.08148184]]]
```

Comment: thanks a ton @Bazingaa ! for your suggestion as well!